# What are the various kinds of graphs that can be defined on $C(X)$

Tags: graph-theory, gn.general-topology, continuity

I was considering the space $C(X)$ where $X$ is a topological space and $C(X)$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$.

What are the various kinds of graphs that can be defined on them?

One possible graph is $f\sim g\iff fg=0$ which is commonly known as zero divisor graph.

What are other ways where we can utilize properties of $C(X)$ to find graph theoretic properties?

Can someone kindly direct me to some possible research going on in this direction and maybe also provide some research links?

Thank You.

Comment: What can we learn from the zero-divisor graph on $C(X)$? What graph properties are interesting for it? People mostly study $C(X)$ to see what it tells about $X$ and vice versa.